# Evaluate $S=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k-1}} k \sum_{n=0 }^\infty \frac 1 { k \cdot 2^n+1 } $

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I am stuck in this problem, which is to evaluate the following series:

$$\sum _{k=1}^\infty \frac {(-1)^{k-1} } k \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac 1 {k \cdot 2^n +1}.$$ I have to solve it using high school methods. I tried to by expanding the inner sum. I also thought in the direction of limit of infinite sum but not able to proceed, even the first step. Please help.

Comment: What is the question ?

Comment: Find the sum @TheSilverDoe

Comment: Why not try partial fraction decomposition?

Comment: I can't remember, even in rather advanced mathematically high schools, any infinite series except infinite geometrical series..

Comment: @NinadMunshi Partial fracion decompositions... *of what* ?

Comment: @DonAntonio obviously of $\frac{1}{k(k\cdot 2^n +1)}$. I am looking at the same problem that you are.

Comment: @NinadMunshi "Obviously" only, imo, if you form that thing as a double series...ok.

Comment: @DonAntonio I don't understand the point of your last comment. It is a double summation, what do you mean by "if" you form it as one?

Comment: @NinadMunshi I mean it is not exactly given as a double summation and the OP asks to do it with high school methods (?)...whatever that means.

Comment: @DonAntonio I understand the confusion with the "high school methods" that's very context dependent. But this is not a product of two summations. That's like saying $$\int_a^b dx\:x\int_c^d dy\:\sin(xy)$$ is not "given as" a double integral because I didn't put the integral signs together - that's ridiculous. Look at the thing on the inside, it has both index variables.

Comment: @NinadMunshi Take it as you want...and if you know so well then give the OP a hint and stop this. Once again, since apparently you didn't understand the first times: if the OP asks for high school methods, one tries to see it that way. That's all. Have a nice day.

Comment: A similar question was asked a few days ago. [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3816455/evaluating-the-product-of-two-infinite-sums)

Comment: @MichaelHardy Note that $k 2^n+1\ne k(2^n+1)$?

Comment: @DonAntonio can it be converted to integral

Comment: @architavyas I can't really see how..Perhaps some elliptic integral of some kind, but I honestly don't know.

Answer (score 5):

Let $$a_k=\sum^\infty_{n=0}\frac1{k\,\left(k\cdot2^n+1\right)}.$$ Obviously, $a_k<2/k^2,$ so both $\displaystyle\sum^\infty_{k=1}a_k$ and $\displaystyle\sum^\infty_{k=1}a_{2k}$ converge. Now $$\sum^\infty_{k=1}(-1)^{k-1}\,a_k=\sum^\infty_{k=1}a_k-2\,\sum^\infty_{k=1}a_{2k}=\sum^\infty_{k=1}(a_k-2\,a_{2k}),$$ and
$$a_{2k}=\sum^\infty_{n=0}\frac1{2k\,\left(2k\cdot2^n+1\right)}=\frac12\,\sum^\infty_{n=0}\frac1{k\,\left(k\cdot2^{n+1}+1\right)}=\frac12\,\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac1{k\,\left(k\cdot2^n+1\right)},$$ which is just $$\frac12\,\left(a_k-\frac1{k\,(k\cdot2^0+1)}\right)=\frac12\,\left(a_k-\frac1{k\,(k+1)}\right),$$ i.e.
$$a_k-2\,a_{2k}=\frac1{k\,(k+1)}.$$
Thus, $$\sum^\infty_{k=1}(-1)^{k-1}\,a_k=\sum^\infty_{k=1}\frac1{k\,(k+1)}=\sum^\infty_{k=1}\left(\frac1k-\frac1{k+1}\right)=1.$$